# Как починить «проклятую» строчку кода в MicroPython?

Tags: python, micropython

Пишу программу для робота на платформе Lego Mindstorms EV3 на MicroPython. Пытаюсь запустить, выдает SyntaxError: invalid syntax на 20 строчке. Менял местами 20 и 21 строчки, оставлял 20 строчу пустой - всё равно одна и та же ошибка, именно на 20 строчке.
Вот кусок кода, в котором возникла проблема:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython
from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import (Motor, TouchSensor, ColorSensor, InfraredSensor, UltrasonicSensor, GyroSensor)
from pybricks.parameters import Port, Stop, Direction, Button, Color
from pybricks.tools import wait, StopWatch, DataLog
from pybricks.robotics import DriveBase
from pybricks.media.ev3dev import SoundFile, ImageFile


# This program requires LEGO EV3 MicroPython v2.0 or higher.
# Click "Open user guide" on the EV3 extension tab for more information.

# Create your objects here.
ev3 = EV3Brick()
mb = Motor(Port.B)
ma = Motor(Port.A)
mc = Motor(Port.C)
touch = TouchSensor(Port.S2)
ir = InfraredSensor(Port.S1)
color = ColorSensor(Port.S3)
# Write your program here.
ev3.speaker.beep()
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Starting: brickrun --directory="/home/robot/EV3_PRINTER" "/home/robot/EV3_PRINTER/main.py"
----------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robot/EV3_PRINTER/main.py", line 20
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
----------
Exited with error code 1.
```

Comment: В Google Colab на обычном питоне отрабатывает без ошибок.

Comment: Что конкретно у вас в этой строке? Если оставить только эту строку, будет ли ошибка синтаксиса?

Comment: Не знаю, но мало ли, код не попадает на исполнение. По приколу удалите вообще весь код, оставьте какой-нибудь `print`. Ошибка все еще будет на 20-й строке?:)